# Python JSON data load perplexing "expecting , delimiter" error

Tags: python, json, delimiter

Trying to implement this code and keep getting the following error. I have searched and tried everything and nothing gets me past it.

```
import json
import sys
import re
import os
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
path = '/Users/.../'  #(The actual path is in my code)
textfiles = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'/Users/.../'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            textfiles.append(file)
        for filename in textfiles:
            with open(path + filename) as json_data:
                data = json.load(json_data)
                opinion = data['plain_text']
                f = open(path + filename, 'w')
                f.write(opinion)
                f.close()
```

Then, I keep getting this error:

> ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 17 column 3 (char 765)

Comment: the problem is within the json file. it is not correct.. you have to look at the json.

Comment: Thank you.  That was helpful.  I will stop looking at the code and go examine the files.

Comment: you can maybe make use of a JSON validator.. it may save you looking through by eye.

Comment: Johnashu:  Any suggestion since I am using this code to process thousands of JSON files?  How would I go about isolating the one JSON file that is causing this error?  (If that is even possible)

Comment: I have provided an answer that shows you how to catch errors.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously your problem lies within the JSON files.. But which one?? where??

If you put in a `try/except` clause, you can log and see which files are causing the problem so you can debug a little easier.

```
import json
import sys
import re
import os
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
path = '/Users/.../'  (The actual path is in my code)
textfiles = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'/Users/.../'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            textfiles.append(file)
        for filename in textfiles:
            try:
                with open(path + filename) as json_data:
                    data = json.load(json_data)
                    opinion = data['plain_text']
                    f = open(path + filename, 'w')
                    f.write(opinion)
                    f.close()
            except ValueError as e:
                print(filename) # Gives the filename
                print(e)  # Gives the location of the problem in the file
```

Also it should continue to iterate through the files and provide errors on the ones that are problematic.

You can even save to a log.txt for processing later..

here is a little example

```
lst = [1, 2, '3', 4, 5]

for i in lst:
    try:
        l = 123 + i
        print(l)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

output:

```
124
125
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
127
128
```

Comment: Great.  Thank you!  I will work with this and incorporate it in and get a log of the errors.  Great.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying there's a missing comma in line 17 in one of your JSON files. Which one? There should have been more context in the error, but if not you should try to isolate it by processing smaller batches of files.

Also, why would you have 700+ characters in the JSON data?

Comment: I have a batch of JSON files actually.  They are long documents scraped from the web and many have 700 plus characters in them.  Now the challenge is, the error does not indicate which of the 100,000 files in the folder that I am trying to deal with has the faulty JSON.  So, this is another challenge.

Comment: Binary search then? Break them into two batches, sized at 50K each. Then 25K each and so forth. But really, the error should have said which file it's talking about.